# CodeChef - Runtime error(SIGSEGV)

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am getting a runtime error after I submit the solution on Codechef. I can compile and execute the solution in Code blocks on my machine. Please check the code and let me know what is wrong.

Problem definition -

All submissions for this problem are available.

In a company an emplopyee is paid as under:
If his basic salary is less than Rs. 1500, then HRA = 10% of base salary and DA = 90% of basic salary. 
If his salary is either equal to or above Rs. 1500, then HRA = Rs. 500 and DA = 98% of basic salary. If the Employee's salary is input, write a program to find his gross salary.

NOTE: Gross Salary = Basic Salary+HRA+DA
Input

The first line contains an integer T, total number of testcases. Then follow T lines, each line contains an integer salary.
Output

Output the gross salary of the employee.
Constraints

1 ≤ T ≤ 1000
1 ≤ salary ≤ 100000
Example

Input

3 
1203
10042
1312

Output

2406
20383.2
2624

My solution -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    int arr1[10];
    double arr2[10];
    int t,t1;
    int i,j;
    float HRA,DA,GS;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr1[i]);
    }
    i=0;
    t1=t;
    while(t>0)
    {
    if(arr1[i]<1500)
    {
        HRA=(0.1*arr1[i]);
        DA=(0.9*arr1[i]);
        GS=(arr1[i]+HRA+DA);
        arr2[i]=GS;

    }
    if(arr1[i]>=1500)
    {
        HRA=500;
        DA=(0.98*arr1[i]);
        GS=(arr1[i]+HRA+DA);
        arr2[i]=GS;
    }
    i++;
    t--;
    if(i==t1)
    break;
}

for(j=0;j<i;j++)
{
    printf("\n%g",arr2[j]);
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: WHich error do you get?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with proper indentaion/formating.

Comment: @Olaf Successful submission on Codechef but a Runtime error(SIGSEGV)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `i` variable in the first loop is indexing an array of 10 elements and it is going from 0 to `t-1`, while the `t` variable is read from user/test script and is not guaranteed to be less than `10`. So once it is more than that, you get an index out of bounds and memory violation.

Comment: I get your point. I have modified the code accordingly but I am still getting the same runtime error.

Comment: 1) **Don't ever** edit the code in question an answer or comment is related to, as it is effectively invalidating that answer. 2) It is even worse now, as the arrays are zero-length.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is now accepted. The question had a constraint

1 ≤ T ≤ 1000

I modified the code to int arr1[1000] and double arr2[1000] and it got accepted.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: On SO the way to thank is to accept the helpful answer.